# Trying to send out SMS notifications in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am currently creating a lightswitch silverlight application and hoping to send out SMS notifications from the phone number supplied. I am wondering if it is possible in lightswitch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll need to do it on the server, not on the client. You'll need something on the client, to "trigger" code on the server. The way most of us have handled this is by using what we have tended to call the "command table pattern" pattern, for the want of a better name.

There is an article by Paul van Bladel, called [BEING SERIOUS ABOUT THE COMMAND TABLE PATTERN](http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=332), which explains the technique in more detail, but essentially it requires that you create a "dummy" table. In code you then "intercept" a record as it's being "added" to the table, either using the information in that record that was being saved or not.

Because you're writing code for the server tier, you can use any .NET code that you want (which means any SMS service that can be called from .NET code, whereas on the client you'd be restricted to Silverlight's subset of .NET code, as well as it's security restrictions.